# How can I block command who has no permission in server at pycord?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I used discord.py before, but because of discord.py developing stop, I was changing all code to pycord.
Also, I was changing bot's command from text type to slash type.

But, I found that 'has_permission' was not provided at slash_command. But I want to block using command in case who don't have enough permission at server. (ex : No Perm user executed ban command)
Is there any way to limit command according to Server user's permission?

```
#code before rewrite(which don't have error)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
@commands.command(name = "ban", usage = "//ban @aaa#0000")
async def ban_command(self, ctx, user_name : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    if await Permission.check_permission(ctx, 1):
        return None
    await user_name.ban(reason = reason)
    if(reason != None):
        await ctx.reply(str(user_name) + "was banned." + "\nReason : " + str(reason), mention_author = False)
    else:
        await ctx.reply(str(user_name) + "was banned.", mention_author = False)


#code after rewrite(which has error)
@slash_command.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
@slash_command(name = "ban")
async def ban_command(self, ctx, user_name : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    if await Permission.check_permission(ctx, 1):
        return None
    await user_name.ban(reason = reason)
    if(reason != None):
        await ctx.reply(str(user_name) + "님이 차단되셨습니다." + "\n이유 : " + str(reason), mention_author = False)
    else:
        await ctx.reply(str(user_name) + "님이 차단되셨습니다.", mention_author = False)
```

Comment: I searched around a bit and found [this](https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord/issues/93) on the `pycord` github page. It seems that the API itself hasn't solidified permissions with slash commands, so it seems it just a matter of waiting for it. Maybe it's possible to have a work around using roles?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I will try to check about your opinion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following if statement to check the user permissions:

```
if ctx.author.guild_permissions.ban_members:
    # Code for the ban command
else:
    # Respond with an Error Message
```

Currently discord does not have included special permissions like ban members, kick members etc for slash commands so you need to use if statements in the command itself.